# Chat still says beta

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, graduation

A picture with freehand red circles is worth a million words:

[image]

Comment: [Should I blame caching?](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) Well, at least partially... The image URL in the bottom bar is `//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/img/logo.png?v=cf`, which delivers the wrong image. Changing the cache breaker `?v=cf` to something else (or removing it entirely) gets rid of the **beta** label.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like either a.) someone took care of this, or b.) it was caching.

[image: fixed_lel]

A picture with freehand red circles *and* some freehand red text is worth a million words + one for each freehand word.

Comment: FWIW, it seems several users (including myself) are [still seeing the beta label.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27822005#27822005)

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaand it's gone.

Comment: @Geobits RIP beta label